# Dynamic HTML escaping in template in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask's jinja2 templates to display a webpage. Now whenever a user inputs some data (in Markdown format) in the text field I send a request to the server and the respective view returns that data converted to HTML. Then using jquery I insert that html in a div.

Now, Flask templates won't render the HTML the way it's meant to be. I've tried using Flask's markup and escape on the server side but it still isn't displaying it properly. I have to figure out a way for templates to completely disregard an area of the template and not autoescape it. I've even tried turning off autoescape by using the `{% autoescape off %}` tags but I think that only works for stuff inside `{{..}}` or it only works when the `render template` function is used

Code for reference:

**view function**

```
@app.route("/convert_markdown/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def convert_markdown():

    content = request.args.get('val')
    value = markdown.convert(content)

    return value
```

**javascript**

```
$("#content").bind('keyup', function() {
    var value = $( "input:text[name=content]" ).val();
    $( "#preview" ).text( value );
    $.get("/convert_markdown/",{val:value}, function(data) {
        $( "#preview" ).text( data );
    });
});
```

**template- html**

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: What does "isn't displaying properly" mean? What is `markdown`? Nothing in your question uses Jinja, is this your actual code?

Comment: Markdown is a markup language which is very commonly used due to the ease in formatting and that it's very easy to read even when raw.

Comment: The html part of the code is in a jinja template. That is rendered using Flask. I only included the parts of the code related to my problem.

Comment: My question wasn't "What is Markdown?" It was "What is `markdown`?" Is it a library you installed? Is it code you wrote yourself?

Comment: You don't call `render_template` or anything related to it in the code you provided. It is unrelated to the code you shared.

Comment: oh okay. ```markdown``` is a Python library that is used to handle Markdown and manipulate it. In this case, I am using it to convert data (entered in Markdown) to HTML code.

Comment: and I'm not using ```render_template``` in this particular view because I don't want it to render a template. This view is called by the Javascript function and whatever is returned is inserted in to the div shown in the html section. I don't want to be refreshing the page every time the function is called. It's performing like AJAX does.

Comment: You still haven't answered the first question: What does "isn't displaying properly" mean? What *is* displaying and what are you expecting to be different?

Comment: When the HTML code is returned instead of displaying it as HTML, it's being displayed with everything including the HTML tags.
For example this is the code being returned: ```<b> hi </b>```
Instead of being displayed like:  **hi** it's just ```"<b> hi </b>"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the return value as text, not HTML. Change

```
$( "#preview" ).text( data );
```

to

```
$('#preview').html(data);
```

You can also skip jQuery and use

```
document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = data;
```

Comment: I'll check this out the first thing when I get to work tommorow morning. I'll let you know how it goes. I really hope this is it. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It worked! Just a minor change in the code though. The innerHTML is supposed to be set by ```document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = data;``` .Will accept the answer after you edit and correct it.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I combined the jQuery and vanilla JavaScript. I've updated the answer to include both.